# How can I delete rows and columns that only contains zero's in an 2d array?

Tags: c#

I have an 2d array and I have no idea how I can delete the rows and columns from it in which are only zero's.

```
int [,] test = {   {0, 0, 0, 0},
                   {0, 0, 1, 1},
                   {0, 1, 1, 0},
                   {0, 0, 0, 0}  }

 int row = pieces.GetLength(0);
        int col = pieces.GetLength(1);
        for (int y = 0; y < row; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < col; x++)
            {
                if (pieces[y,x] == 0)
                {
                }
            }
        }
```

So I want it to be this:

```
int [,] test = { {0, 1, 1},
                 {1, 1, 0}}
```

Comment: Copy only the array elements that you want from the old array to a new array.

Comment: But can I make a program so the computer will do it automatically? Because I want this for other arrays too.

Comment: You are not deleting zeros (since there are sill some left in the desired output), but rather omitting rows and columns that contain _only_ zeros. Please [edit] the post and fix the title so it is clear what you want.

Comment: `can I make a program so the computer will do it automatically?` -- Of course.

Comment: yeah, but how? ;)

Comment: what happens when you have such row/column in middle? do you delete it?

Comment: I have never such a row/column in the middle. To be clear, this is a figure of tetris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here this will remove every Column/Row with only zero

```
int[][] test = {   new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0},
                   new int[]{0, 0, 1, 1},
                   new int[]{0, 1, 1, 0},
                   new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0}  };
var result = 
    Transpose(Transpose(test.Where(row => !row.All(item => item == 0)).ToArray()).Where(row => !row.All(item => item == 0)).ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

This basically selects the rows where there isn't a single 0. Now transpose the matrix(its easier to not select rows than not selecting columns) and again select every row where there isn't any 0(meaning there is at least a 1 we need), now transpose back to original order.

here are the helper methods

```
static int[][] Transpose(int[][] originalArray)
{
    int w = originalArray.Length;
    int h = originalArray[0].Length;

    int[][] result = CreateJaggedArray<int[][]>(h, w);

    for (int i = 0; i < originalArray.Length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < originalArray[i].Length; j++)
        {
            result[j][i] = originalArray[i][j];
        }

    return result;
}

static T CreateJaggedArray<T>(params int[] lengths)
{
    return (T)InitializeJaggedArray(typeof(T).GetElementType(), 0, lengths);
}

static object InitializeJaggedArray(Type type, int index, int[] lengths)
{
    Array array = Array.CreateInstance(type, lengths[index]);
    Type elementType = type.GetElementType();

    if (elementType != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lengths[index]; i++)
        {
            array.SetValue(
                InitializeJaggedArray(elementType, index + 1, lengths), i);
        }
    }

    return array;
}
```

you can convert them to extensions if you want since they are static anyway.

Check out the complete example at [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5TnnCc)

Comment: Appreciate it man!

Comment: A comment below OP allows for a simpler solution: iterate the matrix top to bottom, left to right, and keep a track of smallest and largest row and smallest and largest column that contain a non zero value. Then extract that "rectangle" from the matrix. All this if there is no blank row/column in the middle.

Comment: @SalmanA Nice idea, hats off to my senior for always finding a solution better than mine XD

Answer (score 1):

Ok i created a code, that will first create `List<int>` out of each row and column, and add its indexes to another `List<int>` that will mark columns and rows at which '1' does appear. This code uses Linq, to check `.Contains()` if 1 does exists. Rest should be fairly easy to read.

```
int[,] test = { {0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 1, 1},
                {0, 1, 1, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0}};

//get size
int columns = test.GetLength(0);
int rows = test.Length / columns;
//create lists
List<int> nonZeroRows = new List<int>();
List<int> nonZeroColumns = new List<int>();
for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
{
    List<int> rowAsList = new List<int>();
    List<int> columnAsList = new List<int>();
    for (int col = 0; col < columns; col++)
    {
        rowAsList.Add(test[row, col]);
        columnAsList.Add(test[col, row]);
    }
    //check if row & column contains 1
    if(rowAsList.Contains(1))
    {
        nonZeroRows.Add(row);
    }
    if (columnAsList.Contains(1))
    {
        nonZeroColumns.Add(row);
    }
}

//create new array
int[,] result = new int[nonZeroRows.Count, nonZeroColumns.Count];
int irow = 0;
foreach(int row_id in nonZeroRows)
{
    int icol = 0;
    foreach (int col_id in nonZeroColumns)
    {
        result[irow,icol] = test[row_id, col_id];
        icol++;
    }
    irow++;
}
```